# PowerShell .NET Winform GUI freezing while running foreach loop in a function

Tags: .net, multithreading, powershell, winforms, runspace

I have made a lot of progress transforming my primitive PowerShell script into a .NET GUI app, however I have hit a snag with user experience as the GUI is becoming unresponsive while the code is executing a foreach loop within a function.

Am seeking help and guidance with how I can alleviate these daunting issues. I know I have a design flaw here.

- How can I resolve GUI freezing, even though I am running certain CMDLETS in Runspaces, within a foreach loop?
- How can I parse variables in and out of Runspaces without declaring parameters, sending and receiving arguments each time? I have tried creating a hashstable, but don't think I've scoped it out correctly as I had declared this in the RunAppCode function rather than outside.

I have already tried running my probe CMDLETS within the foreach loop in seperate threads including Start-Job and Runspace scriptblocks.

Runspaces have indeed made the code execute slightly quicker, however hasn't resolved the root problem.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
Function RunAppCode
{
#Declare variables.
    $Array = @()
    $FQDN = $null
    $Object = $null
    $getPing = $null

Foreach($server in $serverList)
    {
        $outputBox.Selectioncolor = "Green"
        Add-OutputBoxLine -Message "Processing $server"
        $outputBox.Selectioncolor = "Black"

        #Check FQDN for remote computer 
        $Runspace0 = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
        $PowerShell0 = [powershell]::Create()
        $PowerShell0.Runspace = $Runspace0
        $Runspace0.Open()
        #$runspace0.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("sync", $sync)
        $PowerShell0.AddScript({
            Param($server0)
            #The probe CMDLET I am executing.
            ([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName(("$server0")))})
        $PowerShell0.AddArgument($server)
        $FQDN = $PowerShell0.BeginInvoke()
        $FQDN = $PowerShell0.EndInvoke($FQDN)
        $Runspace0.Close()
        $PowerShell0.Dispose()
        
        #RunSpace Get RDP
        $Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
        $PowerShell = [powershell]::Create()
        $PowerShell.Runspace = $Runspace
        $Runspace.Open()
        #$runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("sync", $sync)
        $PowerShell.AddScript({
            Param($server1)
            #Executing my remote probe CMDLET.
            Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $server1 -CommonTcpPort RDP})
        $PowerShell.AddArgument($server)
        $Object = $PowerShell.BeginInvoke()
        $Object = $PowerShell.EndInvoke($Object)
        $getPing = $Object.PingSucceeded
        $Runspace.Close()
        $PowerShell.Dispose()
    }
    $Var1 = $Object.subclass
    $Var2 = $Object.sublass2
    $Var3 = $getPing.subclass
    
    $Array += [pscustomobject]@{'Variable 1'=$Var1; 'Variable 2'=$Var2; 'Variable 3'=$Var3}
}

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

#Main Form
$script:Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$FormWidth = '500'
$FormHeight = '750'
$Form.Size = "$FormWidth,$FormHeight"
$Form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$Form.text = "Ninja Freezing GUI"
#Disable windows maximize feature.
$Form.MaximizeBox = $False
$Form.FormBorderStyle='FixedDialog'

#Button which invokes RunAppCode function above
$buttonRun = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$buttonRun.text = "RUN"
$buttonRun.Size = '300,40'
$buttonRun.location = '90, 200'
$buttonRun.Font = 'Verdana,11'
$buttonRun.Cursor = [System.Windows.Forms.Cursors]::Hand
$buttonRun.Add_Click({RunAppCode})
```

I have approximately five more probe CMDLETS which are all running in their own Runspace instances within the foreach loop, again I do not believe this is fundamentally good design and it is freezing the GUI.

Really looking forward to any help and guidance you cool guys can offer :)

Comment: You can't leave the GUI hanging for to long or else it will appear frozen. 

Have a look at this classic blog series, [Building Responsive PowerShell Apps with Progress bars](https://www.foxdeploy.com/blog/part-v-powershell-guis-responsive-apps-with-progress-bars.html)

Comment: Looks good Dennis, in theory I should then be able to place my GUI inside a runspace and invoke it rather than let it run in the Main thread.. Will give this a whirl this weekend. Thanks again!